# Adobe/Apache Flex: Modify View in an ActionScript class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, mxml

I have a WindowedApplication in Apache/Adobe Flex 4 which currently consists of one view (the view defined in the WindowedApplication MXML).

In that application I have an object which listens to data coming from a network. When data is available a method is called on that object and it shall update my view by changing the text of a label.

I do not have a reference to the view in the network listener object though. How can I get it?

This is part of my MXML where I define my view.

```
<fx:Script source="./ViewCodeBehind.as"/>

<!-- ommited stuff -->

<s:Label id="errorLabel"
    text=""
    fontSize="14"/>

<!-- Stuff in between -->

<s:Button label="Get Status" 
        click="getStatus();"/>
```

The code which is called when the button is clicked:

```
public function getStatus(): void 
{
    var networkGateway: NetworkGateway = new NetworkGatewayImpl();
    networkGateway.getConnectionStatus();
}
```

And the NetworkGatewayImpl

```
public class NetworkGatewayImpl implements NetworkGateway
{
    public function NetworkGatewayImpl()
    {
    }

    public function getConnectionStatus(): void
    {
        // Start asynchronous network call
        // when error occurs onNetworkError() is called
    }

    private function onNetworkError(): void
    {
        // Set "errorLabel" here: How?
    }
}
```

Essentially I want to know some ways to update "errorLabel" from the NetworkGatewayImpl.

Comment: Please post some code and let us know exactly where you are facing the issue?

Comment: Added the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, there could be multiple ways to solve this. Easiest way (as per me) would be to dispatch an event from the `NetworkGatewayImpl` class and listen to it on the instance you have created in the view class. So sample code would look like this:

```
public function getStatus(): void 
{
    var networkGateway: NetworkGateway = new NetworkGatewayImpl();
    networkGateway.addEventListener("networkError", onNetworkError);
    networkGateway.getConnectionStatus();
}

private function onNetworkError(e:Event):void
{
    networkGateway.removeEventListener("networkError", onNetworkError);
    this.errorLabel.text = "Your Text Here";
}
```

Dispatch your event like this from your `NetworkGatewayImpl` class:

```
private function onNetworkError(): void
{
    this.dispatchEvent("networkError");
}
```

You will have to ensure that your `NetworkGatewayImpl` also implements the `IEventDispatcher` interface to be able to dispatch events.

Also, best practice would be to create a custom Event class (extending the `Event` class) and use constants instead of the literal 'networkError'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this works. One remaining question: Why do you remove the event listener from the networkGateway after you receive the event?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. The removal of the event listener is just a best practice. It helps in releasing objects for the garbage collector. Also, in this case if the getStatus method is called again for some reason, we would end up adding multiple event listeners and never removing them if the remove line is not there. You can also read up on weak event listeners.